# Memory error in C++ - free() invalid next size (normal)

Tags: c++, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

there is my Integrator_Cauchy class:

```
template <typename T_out,typename T_contour ,typename T_in> class C_Integrator_Cauchy: public C_Integrator{
protected:      
T_out (C_Integrator_Cauchy::*Integrator_ref)(T_contour * Contour,T_in * Point);

C_Integrator_Cauchy(int _NumPoints, double _LimDown, double _LimUp, int _NumAps, Integrator_ID id):C_Integrator(_NumPoints, _LimDown, _LimUp, _NumAps, id){}

public:
static C_Integrator_Cauchy * createIntegrator(int _NumPoints, double _LimDown, double _LimUp, int _NumAps, Integrator_ID id ){
    C_Integrator_Cauchy * p = 0; 
    switch (id)
    {
        case qcauchyleg_lin_ID:
            p = new C_Integrator_Cauchy(_NumPoints, _LimDown, _LimUp, _NumAps, id); 
            p->Integrator_ref=&C_Integrator_Cauchy::qcauchyleg_lin;
            p->setNodes(id);
            break;       
        default:
        cout << "Integrator_ID Error" << endl;
            assert( false);
    }
    return p;
}

T_out getResult(T_contour * Contour,T_in * Point){
    return (this->*Integrator_ref)(Contour,Point);
}

T_out qcauchyleg_lin(T_contour * Contour,T_in * Point)
{
    T_out result(NumAps);
    T_out F(NumAps),resF(NumAps),sumF(NumAps);
    T_in N,temp,sumN,resN;
    T_in z_i,dz_i,coordin;
    for (int i = 0; i < NumAps ; i++){sumF[i] = T_in(0.0,0.0);}
    sumN = T_in(0.0,0.0);

    for (int j=1;j<=NumPoints;j++) 
    {
        temp = w[j];
        z_i=(*Contour)[0][j-1];
        dz_i=(*Contour)[1][j-1];
        coordin=(*Point);
        for (int i = 0; i < NumAps ; i++){F[i]=conj(z_i-coordin)/norm(z_i-coordin)*dz_i*(*Contour)[i+2][j-1];}
        N=conj(z_i-coordin)/norm(z_i-coordin)*dz_i;
        for (int i = 0; i < NumAps ; i++){sumF[i] += temp*F[i];}
        sumN += temp*N;
    }   
    for (int i = 0; i < NumAps ; i++){  result[i]=(sumF[i]/sumN); }
    return result;
} };
```

And the easiest main.cpp

```
typedef complex<double> dcx;

typedef vector<vector<vector<double> > > dArray3D; 
typedef vector<vector<double> > dArray2D; 
typedef vector<double> dArray1D; 

typedef vector<vector<vector<dcx> > > dcxArray3D;
typedef vector<vector<dcx> > dcxArray2D;
typedef vector<dcx> dcxArray1D;

int main(int __argc,char *__argv[]){
    C_Integrator_Cauchy<dcxArray1D,dcxArray2D,dcx> * integ_cauchy=C_Integrator_Cauchy<dcxArray1D,dcxArray2D,dcx>::createIntegrator(2000, 0.0, 6.2831, 1, qcauchyleg_lin_ID);

    cout << "Start allocate something" << endl;
    dcxArray2D temp;
    temp.resize(1,dcxArray1D());
    for (int i = 0; i < 8000; i++){
        temp[0].push_back(1.0);
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    cin.get();

 return 0;
}
```

The issue is - after creation of the Integrator_Cauchy in main.cpp, it is impossible to allocate big vector (say i > 4000). It throws:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./main_test: free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0a01acc8 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x75ee2)[0xb74f3ee2]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x1f)[0xb76d6adf]
./main_test[0x804eb95]
./main_test[0x804d337]
./main_test[0x804d4ee]
./main_test[0x804c278]
./main_test[0x8051e4a]
./main_test[0x80515e0]
./main_test[0x804ffe7]
./main_test[0x804e710]
./main_test[0x804cf27]
./main_test[0x80498d3]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb74974d3]
./main_test[0x8049141]
```

although i have more than enough memory space in RAM, and the Integrator_Cauchy itself doesn't take a lot of memory.

I`m compiling on Ubuntu 12.10; g++ 4.7.2;

Any ideas?

Comment: My psychic debugging skills tell me that your `C_Integrator_Cauchy` class does dynamic memory allocation and your code contains either a buffer underrun or a buffer overrun somewhere. As a result of the underrun or overrun, you corrupt critical structures that the runtime uses to track heap memory. And once you do... well... can you blame the runtime for failing?

Comment: something like Address Sanitizer might help you find if you have a buffer overrun/underrun. <http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html>

Comment: Wow that is hard to read; are you `free`ing pointers allocated with `new`? Run it through `valgrind`.